# Copy File Over, then rename VBS

Tags: vbscript

So, I had a user help me out in getting the file renamed, which is fantastic!

Here is the code:

```
 Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set fol = fso.GetFolder("F:\Downloads")

 For Each fil In fol.Files
'may need to specify a comparison
If InStr(1, fil.Name, "tv show bob - 13", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
    ext = fso.GetExtensionName(fil)
    If Len(ext) > 0 Then ext = "." & ext
    sName = "tv show bob S03E13" & ext
    fil.Name = sName
  End If
Next

 WScript.Echo "Completed!"
```

But the issue I come across now is that the file is being used by a torrent program. Right now, for the standard files I use this line of code:

```
If (objFSO.FileExists("D:\TV Shows\tv\tv show S01E02.mkv")) Then
Else
objFSO.CopyFile "D:\Downloads\tv show - 02 [1080p].mkv", "D:\TV Shows\tv\tv show S01E02.mkv"
End If
```

I was wondering if it possible to have it copy the file, then paste the renamed version using the first section of the code. Thanks for your help :D

Comment: I don't understand... You're saying you have all the code and you just need somebody to put it together for you? Sorry to break it to you, but that's *your* job.

Comment: Do not use _literals_ in `if` statement, `CopyFile` method etc. Assign that literal values to applicable named variables and solution will appear itself... And write your _first section of the code_ to be a `function` or `sub` procedure.

Comment: > 
I don't understand... You're saying you have all the code and you just need somebody to put it together for you? Sorry to break it to you, but that's your job.

No, I am not saying that...the code works just fine but it needs some tweaking to work with torrents.